# How to Fix Express Routing

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

  User.findOne({ "email": req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user){
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Authenticated failed, User not found'
        });
    } else if (user) {

        var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
        if (!validPassword) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong Password'
            });
    } else {
        var token = jwt.sign({
            user: user
            }, config.secret, {
                expiresIn: '7d'
            });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: "enjoy your token",
                token: token
            });
        }
    }

});
```

**Error :**

events.js:180
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
    Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (Incorrect arguments)
    at Function.emit (events.js:178:17)
    at C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Ecomerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4640:13
    at C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Ecomerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4345:12
    at process.nextTick (C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Ecomerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2841:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

I don't know what I am missing, can someone highlight the error in the code ?

Comment: just a note, your `else` will never be reached. There is no scenario where `user` will not loosely equal neither true nor false.

Comment: @KevinB this must be the nextTick error i receive but how to get around it , any suggestion, 
I want to throw error if the email is wrong or is the password is wrong , different msg in each error event

Comment: the stacktrace you gave doesn't really provide much insight into what's wrong here. I'd look at adding more error handling, such as on the mongoose connect. Somewhere, there's an error not being caught. The else not occurring wouldn't cause the error you're seeing (it would cause the request to timeout due to you never responding to it)

Comment: @KevinB  here is the error :  
events.js:180 throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (Incorrect arguments) at Function.emit (events.js:178:17) at C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Ecomerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4640:13 at C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Ecomerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4345:12 at process.nextTick (C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Ecomerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2841:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Comment: @Farida Looking at the stack trace and code provided i would suggest you debug 
 `comparePassword` method. Refer this. [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4847#issuecomment-269591677)

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block in your code hope this will help you.